# DMX over RJ45 daisychain extra pins?

Tags: rj45, dmx512

Im building a DMX controller that uses RJ45. (Controller as in lights are connected to it) I will obviously have 2 RJ45 jacks for daisy-chaining. What I was wondering is, I've seen that multiple universes can be carried over RJ45. Should I connect the unused pins of the 2 jacks together so if there is a second universe on the cables it will be passed on to the next controller, or should I just let those extra pins floating? Thanks!

Comment: There are a few varying implementations of DMX. If you can find an existing standard to conform to (or want to be compatible with other specific devices), then design for that.  Otherwise you're on your own in terms of the features you'd like.

Comment: It's up to you, you're the person designing it! Think about how your customers would like to wire their system - would it be helpful for them to put (up to 4?) controllers in series? Or is that something they wouldn't do? How can they access the other universes? Draw some diagrams of how a customer might set up their system. These are called *use cases*.

Comment: I dont think the standards say about that, and it will work with other devices either way. I am using the correct pinout, Im just not sure if I should connect the unused pins through or not.

Comment: Is there any reason to not connect them?

Comment: RJ45 connectors are only allowed on fixed installations, in locations where access is restricted. Standard also says what the pinout is, and any deviation from this is non-standard and implementation-specific. Three pairs are already defined, main data, aux data, and ground pairs, so only the pair used by telephone is left unassigned. Standard also warns that connecting different implementations may damage equipment. Is that enough reason to leave them floating? Besides, if you have two RJ45 jacks, how do you handle bus termination?